# Amazon EC2 CPU Utilization Percentage for Auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I want to create a Step scaling policy and want to add instances for the below CPU utilization values
80% - 85% => Add 1 CPU instance
85% or above => Add 1 more CPU instance

My question is how I can test if that is working fine. Is there any way to achieve exactly 80-85% of average cpu utilization on an EC2 instance? I know about JMeter and other tools but are there any tools on AWS or a third party that can help me achieve exact CPU utilization?

**Note:** This is a windows instance.

Comment: Run something that basically uses 100% of the CPU or put sleeps / waits in to drop it to ~85% CPU. `while (true) { /* busy wait */ }`

Comment: Yea for micro instance having 1vCPU it will make it 100%.

Answer (score 1):

luk2302 points out a valid solution to get to 100% CPU usage, but if you want to get more specific, you can use a tool like `stress-ng` to try to create a core utilisation roughly a specific percentage.

This command basically tells it to stress all cores (`-c = 0`, you can also specify a number here) up to a load of 85% (`-l 85`). As you can see from the history it's not an exact science, modern CPUs and OSs are incredibly complex, but it's good enough for my use cases.

```sh
stress-ng -c 0 -l 85
```

[image]

On Ubuntu you can just install it using:

```sh
sudo apt install stress-ng
```

Credit where credit is due, I found it in a serverfault question a while ago: [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/796225/stress-ng-simulate-specific-cpu-percentages) - the author of the tool even replied there.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this reply but I am using windows instance.

Comment: Ah, I see - I've edited that information into your question, it's kind of important ;-)